# Which java class issues warning on catalina.out

Tags: java, maven, debugging, tomcat, tomcat8

I' am currently debugging why a legacy `Maven` web application compiled in `Java 1.8` that we deploy on a `Tomcat 8.5` is sending all the time following message:

`Warning: Could not get charToByteConverterClass!`

Curiously enough, when launching it on my local Tomcat instance, I see the warning in the console, but not in the `catalina.out` file.

My guess so far is that this is caused by some dependency, as we have no such warning inside our code.

The problem is that we have **very** old dependencies and also lot of them, so before getting into trying to upgrade them I would like to know if there is any way to:

- see the printing "call stack".
- or at least see *which class is printing that*.

Things I have tried so far:

- Setting application log level to info.
- Setting Tomcat's logging level to All.

Comment: do you have xalan dependency, what's its version?

Comment: @user7294900, yes, and it is a quite old one: _2.4.1_.

Comment: "see which class is printing that" - jar files are essentially zip archives, and Java stores constant strings in class files as UTF-8. Thus searching for that string with a tool that  can unpack zip files you should be able to locate the class.

Comment: @KonstantinKolinko, tried that but got no luck. It seems to be a JDK message caused by some internal error in the _xalan_ dependency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to upgrade [xalan](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/XALANJ-2086) due to a fixed issue since 2.7 release:

> issue is now resolved as being fixed in the Xalan-J 2.7 release. As the issue reporter please confirm the code no longer has this problem so that we can close this issue down.

> Actually the code that had the problem is totally gone, haha! Through XALANJ-2087 the dependancy on CharToByteConverter was removed plus a number of bugs were fixed due to an incorrect algorithm.

Comment: We tried that but after upgrading `xalan` we get a `java.io.IOException: Underlying input stream returned zero bytes` exception. Can't tell yet if the error disappears, as this exception might be obscuring it.

Comment: @GuillemVicens you need to update another old jar(s) that depend on xalan, see if you find it on link https://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/downloads.html

Comment: it is way more complicated than we first thought. This application has dependencies that get back to 2004 and further. Upgrading that will need a lot of work. It's pure programming archeology :P
Anyway, we solved it temporarily by reverting to _xalan 2.1_ until we can upgrade all of the dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone encounters this problem.  xalan 2.7 did not eliminate the message.  Adding the following stub class to your build will silence the error message:

```
package sun.io;

public class CharToByteConverter {
    public static CharToByteConverter getConverter(String encoding) {
        return new CharToByteConverter();
    }
}
```